# How to connect to cloud sql from containered application in gcloud?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm using GCloud, I have a kubernate cluster and a cloud sql instance.

I have a simple node.js app, that uses database. When I deploy with `gcloud app deploy` it has an access to a database. However, when I build a dockerimage and expose it, it cannot reach database.

1. I expose Docker application following: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app
2. Cloud SQL deosn't have Private IP enabled, Im connecting using cloud sql proxy
3. In app.yaml I do specify `base_settings:cloud_sql_instances`. I use the same value in `socketPath` config for mysql connection.
4. The error in docker logs is:

   (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/x-alcove-224309:europe-west1:learning
       at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)

Can you please explain me how to connect to cloud sql from dockerized node application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy your app on App Engine with `gcloud app deploy`, the platform runs it in a container along with a side-car container in charge of running the cloud_sql_proxy (you ask for it by specifying the `base_settings:cloud_sql_instances` in your app.yaml file).

Kubernetes Engine doesn't use an app.yaml file and doesn't supply this side-car container to you so you'll have to set it up. The [public doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy) shows how to do it by creating secrets for your database credentials and updating your deployment file with the side-car container config. An example shown in the doc would look like:

```
...
- name: cloudsql-proxy
  image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
  command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
            "-instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306",
            "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
    allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  volumeMounts:
    - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
      readOnly: true
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best method is to connect using a sidecar container inside the same pod as your application. You can find examples on the "Connecting from Google Kubernetes Engine" page [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine). There is also a codelab [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gmemegen) that goes more in-depth and might be helpful.

Comment: Why is sidecar container the best approach?

Comment: @RicoW I usually prefer it for a couple of different reasons: 

Security - The Cloud SQL proxy encrypts connections between itself and the instance, but doesn't do client side SSL. By using the sidecar you avoid exposing any unencrypted traffic.

Control - By packaging the sidecar with application, you are ensuring that ONLY that applications that are supposed to have access to the database, do.

Isolation - Since each pod has its own instance, any issues with a specific pod stay limited to that pod. This helps prevent problems in one pod spilling over and affecting another.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [mentions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) that it is possible to connect using an internal IP address.
Did somebody try it?

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use the comment section for comments or additional questions.